# How to rewrite python class module from root folder without changing the original package module

Tags: python, class, module, package, site-packages

I have a project using python that has site package. I need to do a customization of a class from a module located in site package and used only the custom one. The problem is, I wanted to do it without changing anything in the original site package module. What I have in my mind, I do it by creating folder in project root with the same name as in the site package. Is it possible to do this?

In short, I want to rewrite the class 2 (in site package) with some customization to be class 2 located in project root folder. See the picture below.

**site-package folder:**

[image: site-package folder]

**project folder:**

[image: project folder]

Comment: The usual way to do something like this is to import the class from the package and then create your own subclass overriding the functionality that you need to alter. https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: i get into problem because the views.py (module import in here) is in a package too. so i want to change the class inside the module_a.py (from site-package) by change a class in module_a.py (from project folder)